# What are the ways to connect with a sip server that does not support web socket via javascript say node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sip, wsp

Hello I am now working in a situation where I need to create a sip client using javascript but the sip server doesn't support web socket protocol. Can any one please suggest me some workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you guys starts voting it down? Please comment also if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Did you found any method ?

Comment: Still not. So finally I started working with pjsip. But still I am searching.

Comment: Did you found the answer?

Comment: No, I later developed the application using pjsip.